# UIScrollivew constraint change also reload content?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios-autolayout

I have a horizontal UIScrollview that contains 4 tableview. when user select a row in the tableview , I add a tag and change the size of the scrollview by changing the constraint . However ,after the scrollview size changed , the scrollview is reloaded and show the first tableview no matter which tableview the user was on. Then it will crash. After debugging , I find out the reason is the old tableview has less data than the first one , show it crash in cellForRowAtIndexPath for an out of array bound error. 
My question is why the scrollview will reload and how to make it just change size without reloading the content?

```
// change to the new constrant 
  [self.contentViewConstraint setConstant:height];
  [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

// crash here in cellForRowAtIndex
// reason: index 4 out of bound .... (the current table view has only 3 object while the first tableview has a lot)
  [result fillWithSocialFriend:[self.friends friendAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: Could you post what you are doing in `fillWithSocialFriend`? do you reload the tableViews completely?

Comment: @CatalinaT. I just update some labels in fillWithSocialFriend. I didn't call reload data but after the scrollview size changed , the tableview is reloaded